# Atlas on a smooth manifold that contains 2 charts

Tags: differential-topology

How can I show that if an atlas on a smooth manifold has exactly 2 charts then it is orientable? How do I make sure that the Jacobian of the transition map is positive?

Comment: The Mobius band has an atlas with exactly 2 charts.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. How do I delete my question?

Comment: This good question shouldn't be deleted. It is indeed quite plausible (but false) that an atlas with two charts can be oriented. A good answer should show why the obvious "proof" does not work and what purely toplogical supplementary hypothesis on the two domains of the charts ensures that the result **is** true.

Comment: Here's a modification of your statement that is true: If $M$ is a smooth manifold that admits an atlas with exactly two charts _whose intersection is connected_, then $M$ is orientable. Can you prove that?

Comment: I will think about this Prof. Lee